# 'Package install failed, see above. The Schematic workflow failed. See above' in Angular proyect

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

Estaba camino de comenzar a desarrollar una App en Angular 8, y al intentar crear el proyecto con el comando: ng new  me ha salido el siguiente error:

```
PS D:\Angular_Proyects> ng new carta-online
? Do you want to enforce stricter type checking and stricter bundle budgets in the workspace?
  This setting helps improve maintainability and catch bugs ahead of time.
  For more information, see https://angular.io/strict Yes
? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
CREATE carta-online/angular.json (3671 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/package.json (1213 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/README.md (1021 bytes)   
CREATE carta-online/tsconfig.json (783 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/tslint.json (3185 bytes) 
CREATE carta-online/.editorconfig (274 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/.gitignore (631 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/.browserslistrc (703 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/karma.conf.js (1429 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/tsconfig.app.json (287 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/tsconfig.spec.json (333 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/src/index.html (297 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/src/polyfills.ts (2830 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/src/test.ts (753 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/src/app/app-routing.module.ts (245 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/src/app/app.module.ts (393 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/src/app/app.component.html (24955 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (1075 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/src/app/app.component.ts (216 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/e2e/protractor.conf.js (904 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/e2e/tsconfig.json (274 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (663 bytes)
CREATE carta-online/e2e/src/app.po.ts (274 bytes)
⠴ Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree 
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: carta-online@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.7.1" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\manul\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\manul\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-09T08_45_59_923Z-debug.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Evidentemente parece tratarse de un problema con npm, y concretamente con el modulo de Jasmine.

Ya he probado a eliminar @angular/cli, reinstalar la ultima version, y limpiar la cache, pero no funciona.

Espero si sabeís por donde van los tiros podaís ayudar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el `--legacy-peer-deps` a mi me funciono.

El indicador `--legacy-peer-deps` se introdujo con v7 como una forma de evitar la instalación automática de peerDependency; le dice a NPM que ignore peer deps  y continúe con la instalación de todos modos. Así es como solían ser las cosas con NPM v4 a v6.

Comment: Procura agregar más detalles en tu respuesta: si bien pudo haber sido útil al OP, necesitas detallar tu respuesta para que otros usuarios en un futuro puedan comprender _por qué_ funciona esto. Lee [answer].